# Distinguishing kamatz and patach in tefillin blessing

Tags: blessing, tefilin, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, pronunciation, vowels-nekudot

About the blessing when donning the *tefillin* [Orach Chayim 25:7](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%96) says:

> יברך להניח בקמץ תחת הה"א ולא בפתח ובדגש:‏
>
> He should bless *lehaniach* with *kamatz* under the *hei* and not with *patach* and *dagesh.*

In [Beit Yoseif](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%94#%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3) the [Mechaber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Karo) had already cited that the [Maharil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_ben_Moshe_Levi_Moelin) emphasised the properness of using the language as it is written in [Yechezkeil 44:30](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1244.htm#30):

> וְרֵאשִׁית֩ כָּל־בִּכּ֨וּרֵי כֹ֜ל וְכָל־תְּר֣וּמַת כֹּ֗ל מִכֹּל֙ תְּרוּמ֣וֹתֵיכֶ֔ם לַכֹּֽהֲנִ֖ים יִֽהְיֶ֑ה וְרֵאשִׁ֤ית עֲרִסֽוֹתֵיכֶם֙ תִּתְּנ֣וּ לַכֹּהֵ֔ן **לְהָנִ֥יחַ** בְּרָכָ֖ה אֶל־בֵּיתֶֽךָ׃
>
> And the first of all the first-fruits of every thing, and every heave-offering of every thing, of all your offerings, shall be for the priests; ye shall also give unto the priest the first of your dough, to cause a blessing **to rest** on thy house.

This is perfectly fine with respect to not [geminating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination) the *n.* Being an Ashkenazi, the Maharil obviously didn't have any problems with differentiating between *kamatz* and *patach* either. But what should *Sefardim* do, who don't distinguish the two vowels?

Coming from Bagdad, the [Kaf haChayim](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%96#%D7%9B%D7%A3_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D) understood the problem, and he proposed to lengthen the syllable, but in that case you may overcompensate and fail to put the primary stress on *leha**ni**ach.* Did later authorities confirm his ruling? Or should Sefardi Jews make an effort to pronounce the two vowels in a different way?

<sup>Possibly related: [Sefardi rishonim who differentiate between Patach and Kamatz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37014/15256)</sup>

Comment: Why are you assuming Ashkenazim and Sefardim spoke hebrew the same 500 years ago as they do now?

Comment: @DoubleAA This is one part of the question; it seems that R' Karo could have distinguished the two. On the other hand, there's evidence, that there were traditions that didn't have separate kamatz/patach even 1000 years ago.

Comment: This is a pretty convoluted way to ask if people spoke exactly the same 500 years ago. The question of what people do in general who don't distinguish two different phonemes when they form a minimal pair is also more convoluted than necessary.

Comment: @DoubleAA Edited out R' Karo and the historical part.

Answer (score 0):

Sephardim do differentiate between the vowels. The only reason many modern Sephardim don't, is because of influence from Ashkenazim, modern Hebrew, and many Western languages, all of whom don't differentiate between vowel lengths like we are supposed to.

Even Sephardim who don't differentiate between most vowel pairs, still differentiate between patach and kamatz: Patach is short A like in "Ant", and Kamatz is in between the O in "Octopus" and O in "Ore".

If someone is unaware of any way to make a distinction between the two vowels, then it's okay: The main point is NOT to double the Nun letter. The vowels were only mentioned because letter-doubling and different vowels are intricately connected according to the rules of grammar.